# Create new dataframe from repeating data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am currently trying to prepare a data for training and it is in yaml format so i managed to convert into a dataframe. The useful information is in the format of a subsegment making it impossible to access. I would like to take the column with the 3 subsegments and create and new dataframe since that's the data I need

Dataset head:

[image: Dataset head]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame3 = frame2.explode('annotations').reset_index(drop=True)

frame3 = pd.concat([frame3, frame3['annotations'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
frame3 = frame3.drop(columns=['annotations'])
frame3 = frame3.loc[:,~frame3.columns.duplicated()].copy()
```

Using this solved my issue and opened the dataset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).